# How to get a list of all keys across all documents in a RethinkDB table?

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a dynamically populated table in which documents can have different keys that are not known in advance:

**Document 1**

```
{
 'attribute1': 'foo',
 'attribute2': 'bar'
}
```

**Document 2**

```
{
 'attribute1': 'foo',
 'attribute3': 'baz'
}
```

How can I get a list of all attributes present in all documents?

```
attribute1
attribute2
attribute3
```

I've tried grouping by `keys()` but I get a list of the possible attribute combinations, not the individual keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this isn't fast enough if you have a lot of document, it will eventually finishes and won't consume lots of memory:

```
r.table('table')
  .map(r.row.keys())
  .reduce(function(left, right) {
    return left.setUnion(right)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be slow, but you can write something like `table.concatMap(function(row) { return row.keys(); }).distinct()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a solution that is more efficient than O(n) (?) unless you update some custom meta-data by each data update, but anyways, I guess I'd go

```
  table.reduce(function(left, right) {
    return left.merge(right)
  }).keys()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a secondary index of type multi:

```
r.table('foo').indexCreate('all_keys', function(d){
  return d.without('id').keys()
}, {multi: true})
```

And to get all the keys, just run:

```
r.table('foo').distinct({index: 'all_keys'})
```

Voila ;-)